# Using Azure Synapse with Java

Tags: java, azure, azure-synapse

I have a requirement to read parquet file. I wanted to understand if there is a way we can query the parquet file using Azure Synapse SQL from Java application. Any reference will be appreciated.

Comment: The Java SDK can connect to a SPark pool in Synapse that can work with Parquet files: https://azuresdkdocs.blob.core.windows.net/$web/java/azure-analytics-synapse-spark/1.0.0-beta.1/index.html I would also suggest taking a look at the guidelines for asking good questions. Please specify the specific problem you are having and what you've already tried to resolve it.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Try to connecting to serverless SQL pool like you would connect to SQL Server or Azure SQL Database.

Once connected, to query parquet files take a look at this article:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/query-parquet-files